# Angular form validation - $invalid attribut in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

[Here is a link to a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9tOkMrTWORRZSwHKgreT?p=preview). I can't understand how this works:

```
ng-class="{'has-error': timepickerForm.time.$invalid}"
```

Can someone explain me how the validation work here? who is responsible for checking if `timepickerForm.time` is valid or not?

Comment: The Plunkr link you provided is invalid

Comment: Fixed the plunker. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) checks for rules given on the form inputs.

for example

`<input ng-model=myModel required>`

In case this input is `$pristine` (untouched) the form will be invalid.

You can specify many more rules:

> Built-in validation tokens:
>
> email, max, maxlength, min, minlength, number, pattern, required and url

Comment: so how to put validation for the date and the time? like it seen in the plunker.

Comment: @vlio20 And you can use your own directive with ngModel and validate model by yourself.

Comment: looks like it is being handled by the `bs-timepicker` directive. You could achieve this using a regex pattern

Comment: @vlio20 in your case bs-timepicker directive probably validate the model. You can ask question how to create your own validator if that's what you want to know.